# Modifiers for find queries in Sailsjs Blueprints

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Going through the Sailsjs Docs for Blueprints for [`find where`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-where), I came across the following paragraph:

> Instead of filtering based on a specific attribute, you may instead choose to provide a where parameter with a Waterline WHERE criteria object, encoded as a JSON string. This allows you to take advantage of contains, startsWith, and **other sub-attribute criteria modifiers** for more powerful find() queries.
>
> e.g. ?where={"name":{"contains":"theodore"}}

Where do I find **other sub-attribute criteria modifiers** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the section you want is Query Language [Documentation Here](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language)

In there you will see all the various criteria modifiers which currently contain:

```
'<' / 'lessThan'
'<=' / 'lessThanOrEqual'
'>' / 'greaterThan'
'>=' / 'greaterThanOrEqual'
'!' / 'not'
'like'
'contains'
'startsWith'
'endsWith'
```